# drupal views exposed filters not visible in linux installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I have a view with exposed filters, which is visible and working fine in windows installation. But after i moved it to Linux installation, the exposed filters are not visible in view preview and in actual view page. Your help much appreciated.

Thanks,
Sagar.

Comment: There should be no difference like this between a windows or a linux based Drupal system. Compare the PHP versions used on both systems, check the logs for PHP errors, and double check that you've migrated all your settings between the two systems (especially roles and permissions).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a possible browser compatibility issue (if you're using Seamonkey or something), but I highly doubt it. Like Henrik said, your OS has nothing to do with this as long as you are running similar versions of PHP. Double check this.

Another possibility might be that your theme is detecting your linux-based browser differently than its Windows/Mac counterpart and is applying some sort of compatibility stylesheet to your layout, but this is highly unlikely.